# I updated my Windows 8 and I can't turn the wifi on anynmore

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

My laptop ran out of battery last night and then it shut down. When I turned it back on, the wireless was off and there was no way I can turn it back on. Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> doesn't work, going to settings the ***off/on*** switch is disabled.

I also tried to recover the system to a earlier point in time, it removed the windows updates but the wireless adapter still wouldn't turn on.

I also tried to download the latest driver for my adapter, but that didn't work either.
When windows troubleshoots the problem, it says that the adapter should be activated.

My adapter is an Atheros AR5B93.

Is there any other way I can troubleshoot this issue or does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Have you attempted to remove the device and reinstall the drivers from scratch.  If you could post the device manager information on the device itself also.

Comment: Will do as soon as I get home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. I tried a lot of things. I looked at BIOS and even formatted my computer. Nothing fixed.
The thing that really fixed was booting on linux (using a live CD) and enabling the adapter there and rebooting the computer to windows. It worked from the start.
Someone made some big mistake, either I or Microsoft (or both ;) )

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

Was the adapter disabled for some reason? In my 9 months of windows 8 this happened twice. In Windows 8 the (new control panel) PC Settings metro app can override the system Wi-Fi settings.

Look at the following link and particularly the Wireless settings and confirm that the adapter is enabled or even detected. 
(http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-8-pc-settings-complete-guide/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with network adapter: broadcom 802.11abgn wireless SDIO. I fixed the issue. Go back to an older version of the driver in device manager. You can do this offline!